# Cannot find module '@angular/elements' : Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I am new to angular right now angular 7 using.I want to create angular elements so importing import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements' but it giving error  Cannot find module '@angular/elements'.
Any help will helpful.

Comment: Did you run `npm install` ?

Comment: yes.I did upgrade angular 2 to 7.

Comment: And do you see `@angular/elements` installed inside node_modules folder? If not you have to install that `npm install @angular/elements`

Comment: done.i did npm install @angular/elements and new package elements added.Thank you!!.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have probably not installed `@angular/elements`. Please install it.

Run
`npm install @angular/elements`

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative

```
ng add @angular/elements --project=*your_project_name*
```